# Blocking outgoing requests to specific domains e.g. facebook, twitter

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm finding that **Firefox and Chromium are both ignoring my /etc/hosts file.**

Is there a way for me to block all outgoing requests to a particular set of domains e.g. Facebook.com and Twitter.com.

For instance, if I use nslookup to get a set of CIDR ranges, can I tell the firewall (UFW) to block these ranges?

**Or alternatively** how hard would it be to set up a DNS on my own Linux desktop computer?

Ideally I would have a tool like opensnitch but this isn't compatible with Debian.

Comment: If firefox is your problem, why not block facebook and twitter directly in firefox, as with ublock origin. Or if you don't "trust" ublock or adblock, with your own [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest).

Comment: "how hard would it be to set up a DNS on my own Linux desktop computer?" `dnsmasq` can be a very simple solution. By default, it just serves the names/addresses it finds in /etc/hosts.

Comment: I've looked into writing an extension but it seems to be an unnecessarily elaborate undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

> and I find that Firefox is ignoring my /etc/hosts file

It must not, check: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1453207

Please make sure you're running Firefox 83 or higher where this bug has been fixed. Alternatively try disabling DNS over HTTPS: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-dns-over-https

Comment: I'm using Debian for ARM64, so we don't receive the latest Firefox. I've got 78 ESR. I've tried getting Debian people to update their code but they often don't even answer emails.

Comment: If I could switch to Gentoo I would, although it might take weeks to compile that distro on a Pi.

Comment: Ubuntu features an up to date Firefox version and contains a comparable number of packages if not more, considering various PPAs.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally I would have a tool like opensnitch but this isn't compatible with debian.

Why is it not compatible? There're deb packages for multiple architectures: https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/releases

> can I tell the firewall (UFW) to block these ranges?

You can use a rule similar to this one: `ufw deny out proto tcp from any to x.x.x.x/xx`

Comment: My daily driver computer is the Raspberry Pi 4. OpenSnitch doesn't compile on Raspberry Pi OS. Something called proto is missing and the github page doesn't suggest where to get it.

Comment: If you could explain where to find "protoc" that would help. It's a blocker at this point.

Comment: Could you try to install arm64 packages? daemon: https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/releases/download/v1.3.5/opensnitch_1.3.5-1_arm64.deb and GUI: https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/releases/download/v1.3.5/python3-opensnitch-ui_1.3.5-1_all.deb 

If you want to compile it from sources, protoc can be installing with the second step of the installation instructions: https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/releases/download/v1.3.5/python3-opensnitch-ui_1.3.5-1_all.deb (go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go)

Comment: I made a little progress (I'm totally new to Go) but I do get this error: make[2]: pylupdate5: Command not found

Comment: great! pylupdate5 is part of the pyqt5-dev-tools package (you can use dpkg -S <command> to lookup what package ships what command. But why you just don't install the .deb package? It should be easier. If you have any problems installing the GUI package don't hesitate to open an issue on github.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which QT package lrelease is a part of? I'm getting this error: lrelease: could not exec '/usr/lib/qt5/bin/lrelease': No such file or directory

Comment: dpkg -S lrelease, it seems to be part of qttools5-dev-tools or qtchooser

Comment: Now it's make[1]: pip3: Command not found..... but
dpkg -S pip3 doesn't tell me what it belongs to. And it's not in python-packaging.

Comment: pip3 is part of the python3-pip package (documented in the wiki https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch/wiki/Compilation), but I insist on installing the deb package, it's gonna be easier to install it :)

Comment: I build everything from source, if possible. The main way people get malware onto their computers is by blinding installing "free" software. OK the latest error is:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-install-fsy2fw63/pyqt5/setup.py'